# kubuntu dolphin trash error

Tags: kubuntu, virtual-terminal

I need major help...I have a Linux Ubuntu running computer. I'm trying to delete my trash folder which at the time of doing so is empty, but it keeps popping up as an error. I tried millions of things in my terminal. But it doesn't seem to be the problem or I'm doing it wrong. Help me!Please!

Comment: Consider adding details about the error?